# how to load and make app scaffold from database in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using mysql database with following tables and columns:

table masterProduct: (id,name,description, image).

everything is already set&ready in database.yml(connected with database) file, and in Gemfile (gem 'mysql').

When i do :rails new Product , i would like to load all the info i have in database but as scaffold, so i can edit/delete items which are already there or add new ones.
I've been looking on some tutorial like, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-scaffolding.htm but it didnt help me a lot, since he created a database manually, and i used PHPMADMIN.

Any sugestions?

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: `rails new` will create a new app - what exactly are you asking - it sounds like you're looking for https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Comment: well to create a new app, which will load all info from already connected database.

Comment: hmm... I would doubt that it's going to work as well as you want. I would create your app into a new db and then import the whole db via mysqldump or other tool and then adjust either data or app. To be honest, I had a PHP app where we used rails naming conventions and it worked really well - like a couple of hours of fiddling with it.

Answer (score 0):

Manage your database manually is very bad idea. Rails has awesome features to do this like migrations, seed, etc. When you need update your db schema, you create a new migration to do that. This is the best and easy way. But...

Dynamic scaffold was removed in Rails 2. However you have some options:

1) You can try the gem activescaffold. Other gems like rails_admin or activeadmin are awesome to generate admin views.

2) When you execute

```
rails generate scaffold Product id:integer name:string description:text image:string
```

the generator will generate the scaffold files with a migration to create your table. So you can execute `rake db:migrate` to update your database schema. You can try execute this generate without execute the rake command once your table already exists. This will not create the file db/schema.rb and you will need to manager database manually (bad idea).